# Passing exceptions with a callback function

Tags: c++, exception

To start with, I don't have access to "modern" features such as `std::future` and `std::async`. I want to perform an operation asynchronosuly. The result is given in a callback. If the operation fails with an exception, I would like to pass it as an `std::optional` parameter, for the handler to examine. Is this considered bad practice and dangerous?

```
void
doOperation(std::function<void(SomeClass*, std::optional<std::exception>)> doneHandler)
{
  try
  {
    auto result = doStuff();
    doneHandler(result, cpp17::nullopt_t);
  }
  catch (const std::exception& e)
  {
    doneHandler(nullptr, e);
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be fine if you did not pass exception by value. You are loosing information.

Comment: By no access to modern features you mean you are restricted to C++98? But std::optional is C++17 feature.

Comment: You will have object slicing with `std::exception` by value.

Comment: `std::function` and `std::future` are C++11, `std::optional` is C++17 so why you can't use `std::future`? Some coding convention limitations in your project?

Comment: @pptaszni: `cpp17::nullopt_t` suggests `optional` has been rewritten (or boost one), and probably other functionality.

Comment: Two handlers (`OnSuccess`/`OnError`) might be more appropriated. or `variant<SomeClass, const std::exception*>`

Comment: Shame about the lack of "modern" features. Because [`std::exception_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception_ptr) looks like it's exactly what you need.

Comment: @Jarod42 we have backported certain features

Comment: std::exception_ptr is something we have and it works great. Thanks.